# XSLT child elements

Tags: apache, xslt, apache-fop

I have xml document like this:

```
<OrdersSchedulePDFView>
   <OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow>      
      <Items>
         <ItemDesc>Content1</ItemDesc>
         <ItemDesc>Content2</ItemDesc>
      </Items>
      <Locations>
         <LocName>Content3</LocName>
         <LocName>Content4</LocName>
      </Locations>
   </OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow>
</OrdersSchedulePDFView>
```

Please, give me an example xsl file, where I can get ItemDesc and LocName elements via template. Thanks in advance
This is my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">   
<xsl:template match="OrdersSchedulePDFView">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">        
        <xsl:for-each select="OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow">       
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="all">           
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">                               
                <xsl:template match="Locations">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="LocName"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>             
                <xsl:template match="Items">                                                        
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="ItemDesc"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>         
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? you could  try `<xsl:template match="LocName">` (if there is no namespace on the elements that we maybe can't see), but what should the template do?

Comment: I need print ItemDesc and LocName elements. But I can't get them via <xsl:template match="OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow">
<xsl:value-of select="LocName"/>

Comment: Why don't you post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Also, show the **exact** output your expect to get.

Comment: When I try to add the entire document, I get a message that there is too much code

Comment: Then minimize - see: [mcve]

Comment: try `<xsl:template match="OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow"> <xsl:value-of select="OrdersSchedulePDFViewRow/Locations/LocName"/>` and get some intro into xslt/xpath, and follow michael.hor257k's advice

Comment: I've added xsl above

Comment: and what would be the output you want? You are trying to copy the "Locations" element into the FO?

Comment: @ВячеславКошман Your XSLT cannot work, because templates cannot be nested. I can't tell you how to fix it, because you still haven't posted the expected output.

Comment: I put the templates separately, but I have javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: Document is empty (something might be wrong with your XSLT stylesheet).

Comment: @Stefan Hegny, yes, i need print Locations and Items elements into the FO

Comment: "print Locations" probably does not mean to copy the XML Elements into the fo, but the text contents of them (xslt-speak: <xsl:value-of ...>) into properly formatted fo, which you don't show. Maybe you have a different question on how fo works?

Answer (score 1):

Although your answer is rather vague, if I'm not mistaken you want the output:

```
<output>
    <ItemDesc>Content1</ItemDesc>
    <ItemDesc>Content2</ItemDesc>
    <LocName>Content3</LocName>
    <LocName>Content4</LocName>
</output>
```

The first method that would spring to mind is using recursive templates:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OrdersSchedulePDFView">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ItemDesc">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="LocName">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

This iterates over each node, and when a matching template is found the `copy-of` is executed.

You mentioned in your comments that you would also like a `for-each`. This would looks something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="//ItemDesc">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="//LocName">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: When I try apply
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="//ItemDesc">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="//LocName">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
I get: 
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "fo:root" is missing child elements. Required content model: (layout-master-set, declarations?, bookmark-tree?, (page-sequence|fox:external-document)+) (No context info available)